# How to display year in correct format in Twig?

Tags: php, symfony, date, datetime, twig

I have the problem displaying the correct year format. i have a date column in database `28-04-2021` but twig gives me `28-04-2121` .

My code:

```
{{t.dateLeasing|date("d-m-yy}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `Y`. `yy` means two digit representation of the year, *twice*.

```
{{t.dateLeasing|date("d-m-Y")}}
```

Comment: But I want to display the full year 2021 not just 21 any idea?

Comment: Yes it gives me 28-04-21

Comment: It shouldn't. Make sure you have a the correct code. `Y` *must* be capitalized